# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los cambios en un observable utilizando Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Tengo el siguiente problema, necesito obtener los cambios en vivo de un JSON para mostrar la data en HTML.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabla',
  templateUrl: './tabla.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabla.component.css']
})
export class TablaComponent implements OnInit {

  datosTabla: any[] = [];
  url: string = 'https://sitio.com/miJSON';

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {
    http.get(this.url).subscribe( (data) => {
      this.datosTabla = data.feed.entry;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Guardo los datos que necesito en el arreglo `datosTabla[]` usando el `subscribe`. Para poder imprimirlos en el HTML de esta manera:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let dato of datosTabla">
        <td>{{ dato.gsx$serie.$t }}</td>
        <td>{{ dato.gsx$temporadas.$t }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Pero necesito que los cambios se vean reflejados sin recargar el sitio, ya intenté utilizando el pipe `async` en el `ngFor` pero me genera el error:

```
TablaComponent.html:9 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
```

¿De qué manera podría consumir y almacenar los datos para que se actualicen en el HTML de forma automática?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando usas `async` lo estas diciendo es que `datosTabla` es un objeto asíncrono (un `Observable`), pero en realidad en tu código `datosTabla` es un `array` normal. Por eso te da el error.

Lo que debes hacer es transformar el observable que te da la respuesta del servidor y guardar ese `Observable` transformado en `datosTabla`. Algo así:

```
datosTabla: Observable<any[]> = new Observable();
url: string = 'https://sitio.com/miJSON';

constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {

  this.datosTabla = http.get(this.url)
    .pipe(
      map((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        return data.feed.entry;
      })
    );
}
```

Ahora sí, puedes usar async en tu plantilla:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let dato of datosTabla | async">
        <td>{{ dato.gsx$serie.$t }}</td>
        <td>{{ dato.gsx$temporadas.$t }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

No es necesario que te subscribas al `Observable` transformado que guardamos en `datosTabla` pero aun así puedes hacerlo si quieres logear algo o hacer algún tipo de operación basado en la respuesta:

```
datosTabla: Observable<any[]> = new Observable();
url: string = 'https://sitio.com/miJSON';

constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {

  this.datosTabla = http.get(this.url)
    .pipe( // Transformamos el Observable y lo guardamos
      map((data) => data.feed.entry)
    );

  this.datosTabla.subscribe(datos => {
    console.log(datos);
    // Hacer algo más con los datos
  });
}
```

Comment: Te agradezco tu respuesta, eso ya me elimina el error del pipe `async` y muestra los datos, pero sigue sin actualizar la información según los cambios en el JSON externo.

Comment: @akko Eso ya dependería del servidor y de como estas enviando las actualizaciones. Tal vez te interese saber acerca de `Server Sent Events`

Comment: @akko Si la respuesta te fue de ayuda, podés marcarla como aceptada ;)